# Generating a GS1-Databar (formerly RSS_14) barcode using ZXing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, console-application, zxing.net, gs1-databar

The below snippet gives error

> No encoder available for format RSS_14

I have referred this [link](https://www.databar-barcode.info/) for generating the barcode in GS1-Databar. I found that the ZXing.Net doesn't support encoding in GS1-Databar. Please provide the  custom way to generate GS1-Databar or steps to generate the same with ZXing.Net.

```
        var barcodeWriter = new BarcodeWriter
        {
            Format = BarcodeFormat.RSS_14,
            Options = new EncodingOptions
            {
                Height = 250,
                Width = 500,
                GS1Format = true
            }
        };

        var bitmap = barcodeWriter.Write("01234567891345");

        bitmap.Save(RSS_14, ImageFormat.Png);
        Console.ReadLine();
```